# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree._criterion'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am able to import sklearn on jupyter notebook. however, when I am trying to import "DecisionTreeClassifier", I am facing "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree._criterion'"  error

Code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
```

Error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-462-f146622b3284> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 """
      5 
----> 6 from .tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
      7 from .tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
      8 from .tree import ExtraTreeClassifier

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py in <module>()
     38 from ..utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     39 
---> 40 from ._criterion import Criterion
     41 from ._splitter import Splitter
     42 from ._tree import DepthFirstTreeBuilder

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.tree._criterion'
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you possibly install scikit-learn with `pip`?

Comment: I installed scikit-learn with conda using following code: conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn

Comment: Hi, add informations about your dev environment: OS, version of Python etc.

Comment: Hi Bartlomierj, OS: windows 8, python3.6.8